Error with att_gt(), arguments must have same length
I am trying to execute a staggered Difference-in-Difference with the agg_gt() function, but I keep getting the error "Arguments must have same length". Of course my dataframe is very small but I tried this for simplification and it gives the same error as my actual dataframe.
This is my dataframe and code:
library(did)

Div <- c(10, 0, 5, 6, 7, 19, 15, 1, 0, 66)
IDI <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
Ti <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001)
PQ <- c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 0, 0, 0, 2003)
test <- data.frame(cbind(Div, IDI, Ti, PQ))

When I try to run the agg_gt function, as below, I get the error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : arguments must have same length.
Stag <- att_gt(yname = "Div", tname = "Ti", idname = "IDI", gname = "PQ", data=test, allow_unbalanced_panel = TRUE, control_group = "notyettreated")

I am aware that the control group is very small, I get the warning about that as well, but not if I use my actual (huge) dataset as input.
Is there anyone who is able to help me with this?

your cbind call is unnecessary. do you have missing data in your real data.frame? Running your example I don't get an error I just get the warning you mentioned. Also please let people know what packages you are using.

I am using tidyverse and did. I do not have any missing values in my data.

sorry I can't reproduce the error, perhaps you can share what your actual data looks like or a sample of it with dput(yourdf)

Cannot reproduce the problem (+1).
